Limits and Analytic functions
Consider a differential equation of the form $P(x)\ y''+Q(x)\ y'+R(x)\ y = 0$ where all of $P(x),Q(x),R(x)$ are analytic.
Then, I divide by $P(x)$ to get $y''+\frac{Q(x)}{P(X)}\ y'+\frac{R(x)}{P(x)}\ y = 0$. Let $\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}=q(x)$ and let $\frac{R(x)}{P(x)}=r(x)$.
In this case, my professor mentions that just proving $\lim_{x \to x_0} q(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to x_0} r(x)$ exist is sufficient to prove that both $q(x)$, $r(x)$ are analytic at $x_0$ but I don't get why. If the limit exists but the function is undefined at $x=x_0$, then wouldn't that not hold?

What are the course pre-reqs?  Typically if someone has taken complex analysis then the complex limit would be taken to show the functions are locally bounded hence you'd infer that the $q$ and $r$ have at worse removable singularities that you can define over [i.e. you define their images at $x_0$ with the limits you took].   But if you haven't taken complex analysis then you need to explain what field you are working over as e.g. $\exp\big(-\frac{1}{x^2}\big)$ has a real limit as $x\to 0$ but isn't analytic there.

The course pre-reqs are calculus 3 and ordinary differential equations. The field I am working over is power series solutions of differential equations.

This hypothetical situation is impossible. Division of power series and the resulting radius of convergence can be very precisely characterized.
